# Archive log files older than 10days without using any zip utility

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, zip

I want to archive/zip all the log files older than 10 days without using any zip utility.

I have tried running below script but no luck so far. Can you please advise what is wrong in the script? I am using a VBScript file and a batch file to run the VBScript.

**Batch Script:**

```batch
set _my_date=%date%
set _my_date=%_my_date: =_%
set _my_date=%_my_date::=%
set _my_date=%_my_date:/=_%
set _my_date=%_my_date:.=_%

set arcpath1="C:\Archieval"

set logpath="C:\test\*.txt"

set TEMPDIR=C:\Test
rmdir %TEMPDIR%
mkdir %TEMPDIR%
FORFILES /D -1 /M *.txt /C "cmd /c xcopy /s %logpath% %TEMPDIR%

CScript  Archieve.vbs  %TEMPDIR%  C:\Archieval\someArchive.zip

pause
```

**VBScript:**

```vb
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
InputFolder = objArgs(0)
ZipFile = objArgs(1)
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, vbNullChar)
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items
objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)
WScript.Sleep 2000
```

Comment: Define "no luck". What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Read [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") *must include* the desired behaviour, *a specific problem* **or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Just at an initial glance, `forfiles` is grabbing the wrong files because the value you put after `/D` is incorrect.

Comment: There is also a missing quote at the end of the `forfiles` statement. (Not sure if that would affect anything..)

Comment: do you have enough permission to read from folder and write to folder?

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Yes, I have enough permissions to read from folder and write to folder.
I need this script to search for log files (.txt files) present at logpath which i have defined in above code and then to zip all the log files to archieval folder without using any zip utility such as 7zip.

I am getting below two errors:
1. No files found with the specified search criteria.(I have placed few old files at this location to test the same)
2. VBScript compilation error: syntax error.

Thanks.